Traducción correcta de la expresión: "Las ideas se comparten o se combaten. Las ideas exigen luchar por ellas o contra ellas"
No puedo entender totalmente lo quiere decir esta frase en español, o como se traduciría correctamente al inglés.
“Las ideas se comparten o se combaten. Las ideas exigen luchar por ellas o contra ellas."
Mi mejor intento sería algo así: "Ideas share or they fight each other. Ideas demand to fight for them or against them" pero no estoy seguro si esa traducción tiene sentido. En particular no sé qué significaría que las ideas "se comparten". ¿Qué comparten y con quién? ¿Comparten sís mismas? No me tiene sentido.
¿Quién exige luchar? ¿Nos exigen o exigen a otras ideas?
No entiendo.
Favor de ayudarme. Espero que toda la gramática de mi pregunta sea correcta y su sentido sea claro.

Google translation is perfect.

"Se comparten" aquí quiere decir  "estar de acuerdo con ellas", porque implícitamtne eso significa compartirlas con quien la formula. Y lo que exige luchar es la existencia de ideas contrapuestas. Si,  por ejemplo, vives en 1939 en Alemania, y crees que la raza aria es superior, pues entonces compartes las idea con Hitler y debes unirte a las Schutzstaffel,  y si no, tienes que intentar acabar con esa calaña genocida. Lo que no puedes hacer es quedarte al margen, como si eso no fuera contigo. O nazi o partisano, pero no valen medias tintas. Eso es lo que quiere transmitir esa frase.

No, share ideas or fight for them. Pero aqui solo se traduce hacia el español. Las ideas se comparten o se combaten. Las ideas exigen luchar por ellas o contra ellas." Ideas are shared or are fought against. They required fighting for or against them. That google thing is all wrong.

It seems to me that in this case you are trying to take literally a saying that also ends up being a rhyming pun, the essence of which is very difficult to transfer to other languages such as English in this case.
It's like when I try to translate the phrase the name of the game, I understand what it means, but I can't keep the rhyme or make one up and it literally means the same as in English.

Fast response:

It uses reflexive passive conjugation (RAE):

"se" + 3rd plural conjugation


It means that "Ideas are shared or fought against." The "se" here creates an impersonal or passive sense, indicating that ideas, in general, are either shared or fought over by people.


Explained response
Meaning
"The ideas are shared or fought against. Ideas require that we fight for
them or against them."
Conjugation: Pasiva refleja / Reflexive passive
"The pasiva refleja (reflexive passive) in Spanish is used to indicate that an action is performed on the subject without specifying who performs the action."
Uses of Pasiva Refleja:

When the agent is unknown or unimportant:

It is often used when the agent (the doer of the action) is unknown, unimportant, or obvious from the context.

Example: "Se reparan coches aquí." (Cars are repaired here.)



General statements:

It is used to make general statements or describe general truths.

Example: "Se dice que va a llover." (It is said that it will rain.)



Instructions and signs:

Commonly used in instructions, signs, and advertisements.

Example: "Se prohíbe fumar." (Smoking is prohibited.)



Formal and Informal Contexts:

It can be used in both formal and informal contexts to avoid specifying the agent.

Example: "Se vendieron todas las entradas." (All tickets were sold.)



¿Qué comparten y con quién?


Your sentence, pretends to be a mixture of one and two ("Agent is unknown or unimportant", "general statement"). Possibly, it comes from a politician or a philosopher who pretends to make it an axiomatic reality that has to be accepted. (Although you can agree or not with the sentence.)
Also, it may be used with third use (as an instruction):
Dear trolls from the internet, ideas are shared or fought against. We're going to burn the Twitter tag #fightThisIdea.

(warning: not a native speaker)
Ideas get shared or ideas get fought over.  Ideas demand a struggle, either for or against.
This is a very loose translation,  but one that I think gets the gist of the Spanish.  I turned the se constructs into the English get plus passive.  And I changed the object of "demands" from a verb construct to a noun.

Pienso que entiendas las palabras de la refrán, pero no la idea.  Creo que puedo explicar la idea con este ejemplo:

Si tienes un amigo y ambos tienen ideas fuerza sobre algo. Si sus
ideas coinciden, entonces las ideas se comparten. Pero si son
diferentes (y no puedes estar de acuerdo con tu amigo), entonces las ideas se combatirán.


Tu duda es por el uso de se. Este pronombre (si realmente es un pronombre) tiene al menos siete significados diferentes. Uno de ellos es el de la voz pasiva, que tiene la función de convertir en el sujeto a lo que normalmente sería el objeto.

Juan comparte las ideas. -> Las ideas se comparten.

Otra variante es el se impersonal. La diferencia con el se de voz pasiva es que no hay sujeto gramatical (ej: se prohíbe fumar). En tu ejemplo creo que el se que actúa es el voz pasiva y no el impersonal (corríganme si me equivoco); pero el punto es que ambos usos del se, si bien son gramaticalmente diferentes, tienen la misma función: correr el foco del sujeto hacia el objeto del discurso.
Otra forma de entenderlo es cambiar la redacción de nuevo a segunda persona, sin omitir al sujeto del discurso (que no es el sujeto gramatical, sino quien recibe el mensaje), es decir, convirtiendo ‘las ideas’ en objeto gramatical para la primera frase, y agregando el objeto indirecto en la segunda frase:

O compartís las ideas o las combatís. Las ideas te exigen luchar por ellas o contra ellas.

